# C++ Unit Test in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to write C++ applications. I got that version from my MSDNAA access. My Problem is that I want to create unit tests for the C++ classes I wrote.

**Please Note:**
It's standard conform C++, nothing mixed, no C#, it's just C++ that can also be compiled with the g++.

Under *file -> new -> project -> Visual C++* exists something like a "managed testproject":

[image]

However when I create such a project I cannot manage it to add references e.g. to "MyClass.h" and to compile. And I cannot find a simple tutorial for that.

Can anyone help me by showing how to set up a simple C++ Unit Test with Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: just curious, why are you working in the German version and asking help about it on an English language Q&A site?

Comment: Because Im able to speak english and there is no german site that is as much frequented as this one? I could not chose between a german or english visual studio

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two choices for C++ unit tests **Manage Test Project** and **Native Unit Test Project**. You should select the native one, and then just add the includes you want and write the tests.

Here is a dummy example where I include a "foo.h" header, instantiate a `foo` and call one of its methods.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "..\foo.h" // <- my header

#include "CppUnitTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest1
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            foo f;
            Assert::AreEqual(f.run(), true);
        }
    };
}
```

See [Unit testing existing C++ applications with Test Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx) for more.

Comment: Native Unit Test Project was the correct one, the other one caused a lot of compiler errors when I added my own source files. Thx