# Visual Studio 2013 - Test Explorer doesn't show native unit tests

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I've got a really annoying problem with *Visual Studio 2013* Professional - I've got two Unit Tests projects - one of them written in *C#*, and another written in *C++*. Both of them are standard Visual Studio Unit Tests projects. When I build both of them and turn on `Test Explorer` window, only *C#* test methods appears. 
`Test Explorer` doesn't see any of native *C++* test method. 
First - I tried to rebuild specific project - didn't work. Then I tried to clean 'n rebuild entire solution - also didn't work.

Do you have any ideas how to solve that problem?

**UPDATE (SOLUTION) - 03/03/2016**

The problem was caused by *C++\CLI* project in Unit Tests references.
When I remove that project's reference and rebuild unit tests project, everything works fine and `Test Explorer` detects all of test methods.

**Conclusion** - something creepy happens when you are trying to test *C++\CLI* project in native Unit Tests using *Visual Studio 2013* default unit tests template project, which is pretty amazing, because *it should works* - in normal *C++* console application works completely fine.

Comment: Title says VS2013, tag says VS2012. Could you make up your mind please?

Comment: Of course, missclick, sorry for that.

Comment: Make sure both project compile for the same platform (x64 or Win32)

Comment: I compile entire solution as x64.

Comment: Did you read the answer and try the suggestions in this thread?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647771/c-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: I've found a cause of problem. Thanks to all of you for your answers.